# How to place the input cursor back on the previous QlLineEdit box?

Tags: python, qt, pyside

This is what i am trying to achieve...
user inputs username -> then password -> user can either click or press enter to add the account to a list -> the cursor goes back to username lineEdit box.

however, when the user clicks add account or enter, the cursor stays in the password lineEdit box which forces the user to click on username lineEdit box again to add another account.

Answer (score 0):

Use setFocus() on your username lineEdit in the appropriate slot, ie after the new user has been added.